# javascript removing all clones

Tags: javascript, clone, removechild, removeall

```
var counter = 0;

function moreFields() {
     counter++;
     var newFields = document.getElementById("input").cloneNode(true);
     newFields.id = counter;
     newFields.style.display = 'block';
     var newField = newFields.childNodes;
     for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
         var theName = newField[i].id;
         if (theName) {
             newField[i].id = theName + counter;
            }
        }
     var insertHere = document.getElementById("buttons");
     insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}

function clearData() {
     var pricetxt = document.getElementById('price1');
     pricetxt.value = "";
     var qtytxt = document.getElementById('qty1');
     qtytxt.value = "";
     while (counter > 0) {
         var cell = document.getElementById("input"+counter);
         cell.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(cell.parentNode)
         counter--;
        }
     counter = 1;
}

window.onload = moreFields;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjsc16x/AXUbP/)

I would like to delete all of the clones that were dynamically created by the first function when a button is pressed.
I used [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html) to base my script. I know that I could take the easy way out (the way they do it) but I want to learn how to do it this way.

All answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a counter, so just delete all nodes up to the counter value and then reset it.

```
function startOver() {
    var element;
    for (var i = 1; i <= counter; i += 1) {
        element = document.getElementById(i);
        if (element.parentNode) {
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
        }
    }
    counter = 0;
    moreFields();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AXUbP/1/